# python add values to Line3DCollection

Tags: python, matplotlib, line

I want to plot multiple lines in a 3d axis plot. 
I'm plotting the trajectory of a light ray, each line should be colored depending on the time of propagation for each path. 
I want to plot them independently, since I saved them in a binary three structure in which any ray may follow two different trajectories.

I used Line3DCollection, but it doesn't seem to be the right way.

In few words,

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = x
z = x
t = np.linspace(0,1,100)

#here I need to plot these points coloring them in function of t

x1 = np.linspace(1,2,100)
y1 = x
z1 = x
t1 = np.linspace(1,2,100)

#I need to plot also this used the same colorbar used for former values

x2 = -np.linspace(1,2,100)
y2 = x
z2 = x
t2 = np.linspace(1,2,100)

#idem
```

having all the lines colored with the same colorbar scale, like this
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnY73.png).

I tried with the following but the output is not like I expected

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Line3DCollection

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = x
z = x
t = np.linspace(0,1,100)

points = np.array([x,y,z]).transpose().reshape(-1,1,3)
segs = np.concatenate([points[:-1],points[1:]],axis=1)
lc = Line3DCollection(segs, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'))
lc.set_array(t) 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.add_collection3d(lc)


x1 = np.linspace(1,2,100)
y1 = x1
z1 = x1
t1 = np.linspace(1,2,100)

points1 = np.array([x1,y1,z1]).transpose().reshape(-1,1,3)
segs1 = np.concatenate([points1[:-1],points1[1:]],axis=1)
lc = Line3DCollection(segs1, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'))
lc.set_array(t1)
lc.update_scalarmappable()

ax.add_collection3d(lc)

x2 = np.linspace(1,2,100)
y2 = -x2+2
z2 = -x2+2
t2 = np.linspace(1,2,100)

points2 = np.array([x2,y2,z2]).transpose().reshape(-1,1,3)
segs2 = np.concatenate([points2[:-1],points2[1:]],axis=1)
lc = Line3DCollection(segs2, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'))
lc.set_array(t1)
lc.update_scalarmappable()

ax.add_collection3d(lc)

ax.set_xlim(0, 2)
ax.set_ylim(0, 2)
ax.set_zlim(0, 2)
fig.colorbar(lc)
plt.show()
```

plotting [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww1YO.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think one can guess what's wrong with the output. Would you mind adding an actual description of the problem?

Comment: I upload two images to show what is wrong with my output and how I want to plot it

Comment: You need to use the same norm for all collections, `norm=plt.Normalize(vmin,vmax); LineCollection(..., norm=norm)`

Comment: I tried with norm.plt.Normalize(), it doesn't work. The "smartest" thing I thought was to collect all datas and plotting only at the end, all together. I defined a function "getsegs" then plot. I think that once you have used LineCollection you cannot modify the inputs anymore.

Comment: If I use the same norm as commented above, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5xCb.png).